# JQuery PriceFormat and OnChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using JQuery PriceFormat Plugin (http://jquerypriceformat.com/).

My code is as following:

```
$('#valor').priceFormat({
    prefix: 'R$ ',
    centsSeparator: ',',
    thousandsSeparator: '.',
    limit: 8,
    centsLimit: 2
     });
```

However, but I want to be capable of changing a value of another input while the users type the value. For example, the input that I'm using priceFormat in, is a product price. But, there is another input called taxes, for example, that is dinamically changed by the price (let's say that the tax is 1% of the price). I want to be capable of changing the tax value while the user change the product price.

How can I do this?

Comment: There are 2 textboxes, product price and taxes? And the taxes value changes depending on the price value?

Comment: Yes, that's right, Theo.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to change the value of the tax rate as you are typing a value into product price then, you should tap into the **keypress** event for the product price textbox.

Here's the documentation for it along with an example:
http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Heres some pseudo code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#productPrice').keypress(function() {

    var price = $('#productPrice').val();
    // do comparisons with price to decide a tax rate...
    $('#taxRate').val("8.375%");

  });

});
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to calculate onKeyUp and the priceFormat (from this plugin: http://jquerypriceformat.com/) binds the keyup event to an internal function called price_it. So, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved this issued by binding the keyup event to a function like this:

```
function calcularTaxa(){
    //code of function here
}

$("#valor").bind('keyup', calcularTaxa);
```

Hope this help someone. ;D